# validate email pattern in angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation, email-validation

I'm trying to prevent user to submit the form if he types invalid email format, my issue is he can type text and submittd the form successfuly even it present error massege but still submit the form, **I'm not using formGroup** my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="fromEmail">From Email</label>
   <input type="email"  required name="fromEmail" #fromEmail="ngModel" id="fromEmail" 
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" [(ngModel)]="currentForm.subscribers.subscriber[0].fromEmail" class="form-control" required minlength="1" maxlength="100" />
   <div class="color"  *ngIf="fromEmail.errors.required">Email is required</div>
   <div *ngIf="fromEmail.errors &&(fromEmail.touched || fromEmail.dirty)" class ="alert alert-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!fromEmail.errors?.pattern">
         Invalid pattern
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you need to add validation in your submit method.

Comment: thank you for your reply, please explain more or provide me with reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally use a reactive form for this, as it already has a standard e-mail validation. But in your case what I would suggest is:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="fromEmail">From Email</label>
   <input type="text" required name="fromEmail" ngModel #fromEmail="ngModel" id="fromEmail" 
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="form-control" minlength="1" maxlength="100" />
   <div class="color"  *ngIf="fromEmail.errors.required">Email is required</div>
   <div *ngIf="fromEmail.errors &&(fromEmail.touched || fromEmail.dirty)" class ="alert alert-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!fromEmail.errors?.pattern">
         Invalid pattern
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML call the method and pass the value entered in it

```
<input value="{{ emailValidation(value)}}" type="text">
<p *ngIf ="!emailValidation()">ERROR BOX<p>
```

In .TS file make a custom method and it will validate the email, keep it boolean so it can return true and false based on the email

```
   emailValidation(value) {
       // logic
     return true;
      }
```

On submit

```
   <button  (click)="save()" [disabled]="!emailValidation()">Submit</button>
```

p.s It is not the best approach, and it is a pseudo-code but you will get the idea.

Comment: can you add the code ? or the problem you are facing. Also, see the code I have edited it